# Set IGNORECASE and other options for H2 in a Play! Framework test

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2, slick, playframework-2.2

I've setup my Play! (with Slick) application to use H2 when running tests, and it has worked great so far. I'm getting an error now, because of a plain-SQL query that uses lower-case column and table names, and H2 complains that the TABLE (all uppercase) could not be found.

Now I need to set a [few options](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility), `IGNORECASE` for sure, and possibly the `MODE`.

When I setup my database for tests, I use

```
def fakeAppWithMemoryDatabase = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())
```

For development, I use PSQL, so in my `application.conf` file, I have:

```
slick.db.driver=scala.slick.driver.H2Driver

db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
```

[From the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1-RC2/Developing-with-the-H2-Database), I see I can pass settings to the `db.default.url` string, like

```
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=PostgreSQL;"
```

but my `default.url` setting is for my Postgres DB. Is there a way to pass in `MODE` and `IGNORECASE` settings to H2 in this scenario?

I have tried to append `SET IGNORECASE TRUE;` to my SQL query but I still receive the same error.

Comment: If you create the table names with quoted, uppercase identifiers (`create table "TEST"(...)`) then you also need to use the quotes when querying. So I wonder, why don't you just create the table without using quotes (`create table TEST` or `create table test`)?

Comment: jbnunn, please post the scala/slick code doing the query that lead to your problem and the exact error message you get. How did you create the tables? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529384/h2-runscript-command-turns-all-table-names-into-uppercase

Answer (score 1):

Ok, [based off this merge](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/bb10d87a9ba946185de2883af76ea257aab69455) into the Play! code, I figured it out:

```
FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase(options = Map("MODE"->"PostgreSQL","IGNORECASE"->"TRUE")))
```

Unfortunately, `IGNORECASE` wasn't what I thought it was, my tables and columns still need to be capitalized in order for H2 to properly use my plain-SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 
DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
to your Url. It will let you leave the "" out.
With this I will continue to use H2 otherwise I wouldn't. Can't tell why this option is true by default...